# Excel/VBA: Transpose and "Flush" Table

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to automate the following process:

1. There's a table of data that I want to transpose.
2. Then "flush left".

The number of rows and columns will increase as time goes by. The screenshot below should explain better (using SkyDrive): http://sdrv.ms/UdDu1o

[image]

The only way I could think about doing this was using `VBA`, via `pastespecial-transpose` and lots of `do-while` statements to find the start and end of the row before copying. I understand copy and paste tend to slow down VBA programs - does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: At the first glance the same can be achieved also without VBA. Can you upload the table itself?

Comment: Just had a thought (whilst eating my tea :)) - look at _1685_ in the two tables; in the top table it is at the intersection of _Nov something_ and _Nov something_; in the DESIRED OUTPUT table it is at the intersection of _Oct something_ and _Nov something_ - what you are doing does not seem to make sense; or are you trying to move the results into different weeks? **

Answer (score 3):

Table layout is on the image below.
Example spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Transpose_and_flush_data.xls

Output column headers: `=OFFSET($B$2;C15;$A16)`, copied to the right from `C16`.
Output row headerss: `=OFFSET($B$2;0;$A17)`, copied down from `B17`
Helper cells: Output table data row numbers in column A, data column numbers in row 15.

The numeric part of the table can be built with a single formula in `C17`, copied down and to the right:

```
 =IF(B18="";"";OFFSET($B2;C$15;$A17))
```

The Weeks column is ended with "x" to get a blank cell  right for the first data column.

[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: +1 Unless I had to use VBA I'd be following this example - `OFFSET` is a great function.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this quite simply using a `Variant Array`:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim vSource As Variant

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    ' set range to top left cell of table
    Set rSource = sh.Cells(1, 1) '<-- adjust to suit
    ' extend range
    '  this assumes there are no gaps in the top row or left column
    Set rSource = sh.Range(rSource.End(xlDown), rSource.End(xlToRight))
    With rSource
        ' remove Totals
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
        .Rows(.Rows.Count).Clear

        ' capture source data
        vSource = rSource
        ' clear old data
        rSource.Clear
        ' transpose and place data back
        sh.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count)) = _
            Application.Transpose(vSource)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: beautiful code but I just tested it and the result doesn't seem to resemble the desired pattern of the OP result set - your code does the same as `Copy-Pastespecial; Transpose` but the transpose that the user is looking for is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

ok - Have used Chris's code as a template and effectively just added two extra lines of code to get rid of blanks before doing the transpose:

```
Sub ThisWorks()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rSource As Range
Dim vSource As Variant

Set sh = ActiveSheet
' set range to top left cell of table
Set rSource = sh.Cells(5, 3) '<-- adjust to suit
' extend range
'  this assumes there are no gaps in the top row or left column
Set rSource = sh.Range(rSource.End(xlDown), rSource.End(xlToRight))
With rSource
    ' remove Totals
    .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).Clear
End With
'reset rSource
Set rSource = sh.Range(rSource.End(xlDown), rSource.End(xlToRight))

With rSource
    ' delete the blanks - not as tricky as you mentioned in OP!!
    .SpecialCells(Excel.xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Excel.xlUp
    ' capture source data
    vSource = rSource
    ' clear old data
    rSource.Clear
    ' transpose and place data back
    sh.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count)) = Application.Transpose(vSource)
End With

End Sub
```

Before doing the above I spent 90mins bashing my head against a brick wall - I tried to add all the values into an array and then empty them back out in such a way that the order would be correct. If you can see how to get the following to work please let me know as I'm sure it's possible!!...

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ThisDoesNOTwork()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rSource As Range
Dim vSource As Variant

Set sh = ActiveSheet
' set range to top left cell of table
Set rSource = sh.Cells(5, 3) '<-- adjust to suit
' extend range
'  this assumes there are no gaps in the top row or left column
Set rSource = sh.Range(rSource.End(xlDown), rSource.End(xlToRight))
With rSource
    ' remove Totals
    .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).Clear
End With
'reset rSource
Set rSource = sh.Range(rSource.End(xlDown), rSource.End(xlToRight))

Dim tableWidth As Integer
tableWidth = rSource.Rows.Count

Dim numbers() As Variant
ReDim numbers(rSource.Cells.Count)

'add numbers into the array
Dim x, y, z As Integer
z = 1
For y = 1 To rSource.Columns.Count
    For x = 1 To rSource.Rows.Count
            numbers(z) = rSource(x, y)
            z = z + 1
    Next
 Next

' clear old data
rSource.Clear

'empty the array
Dim myValue
Dim i As Integer
Dim blanks As Integer
i = 0
blanks = 0

Dim c As Integer
For c = 1 To UBound(numbers)

        i = i + 1
        If numbers(i) = "" Then
            blanks = blanks + 1
        Else
            rSource.Cells(i) = numbers(c)
        End If

Next c
Debug.Print blanks

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stick to arrays (usually I like it the other way round ;-) Only numeric values are transposed, the user makes the selection. A named range `"Vba_output"` should be pre-defined on the sheet.

```
Sub Transpose_and_flush_table()

Dim source_array As Variant
Dim target_array As Variant
Dim source_column_counter As Long
Dim source_row_counter As Long
Dim blanks As Long

Const row_index = 1
Const col_index = 2

source_array = Selection.Value
' source_array(row,column)

ReDim target_array(UBound(source_array, col_index), UBound(source_array, row_index))

For source_column_counter = _
    LBound(source_array, col_index) To UBound(source_array, col_index)
       blanks = 0

      'Count blank cells
      For source_row_counter = _
         LBound(source_array, row_index) To UBound(source_array, row_index)
           If source_array(source_row_counter, source_column_counter) = "" Then
              blanks = blanks + 1
           End If
       Next

      'Replace blanks, shift array elements to the left
      For source_row_counter = _
         LBound(source_array, row_index) To UBound(source_array, row_index) - blanks
           source_array(source_row_counter, source_column_counter) = _
             source_array(source_row_counter + blanks, source_column_counter)
      Next

      'Add blanks to the end
      For source_row_counter = _
        UBound(source_array, row_index) - blanks + 1 To UBound(source_array, row_index)
           source_array(source_row_counter, source_column_counter) = ""
      Next

      'Transpose source and target arrays
      For source_row_counter = _
         LBound(source_array, row_index) To UBound(source_array, row_index)
             target_array(source_column_counter, source_row_counter) = _
            source_array(source_row_counter, source_column_counter)
      Next

Next

Range("Vba_output").Offset(-1, -1).Resize(UBound(target_array, row_index) + 1, _
  UBound(target_array, col_index) + 1) = target_array

End Sub
```